# Android - problems with ColorStateList xml referenced from shape xml

Tags: android, xml, selector, shapes

I'm running into a problem where the color selector in one of my drawable xml files doesn't seem to be honored.  I have a layout including:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sortLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/listSortBarBackground" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@drawable/filter_button_left"/>
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:background="@drawable/filter_button_left"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

drawable\filter_button_left.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/filter_button_color" />
  <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

and color\filter_button_color.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
    android:color="@color/myred"
    android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item
    android:color="@color/myblue"
    android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

(myred and myblue are defined in colors.xml)

The buttons are rendered and I can tell they are getting the proper checked state since the first one displays with text "ON" and the second one "OFF", both buttons get the shape as their background, but in both cases the shape's color is myred.  I played around with flipping the items in the filter_button_color.xml selector, and it seems that regardless of the actual state or the states in the selector items, the top color is always used.

Can anyone see why this shouldn't work?

Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have the xml drawables the wrong way around.
You need to refer to your selector FIRST from the `ToggleButton` layout, and inside the selector layout, have the two drawables.
Eg ToggleButton -> Selector (With two states) -> Shapes.
This should work (and make one less xml file).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/myred"/>
            <corners 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
                android:topRightRadius="0dp" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/myblue"/>
            <corners 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
                android:topRightRadius="0dp" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I do see that I can make it work by having the original layout point to a drawable selector that chooses between two different shape xml files (a checked and unchecked with specific colors instead of a ColorStateList).  Is that what you have in mind?  I'm confused because that solution results in one more xml file, not one less.  Also, it seems a bit clunkier than what I was trying to implement as the two shape xml files now duplicate the corner radius settings and changes would have to be managed in both places.  In any event it does work, so thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I think you are going to need at least two xml files total (your left and right drawables - assuming they are different). I can see that it's a bit of a pain to have to define the radius part of the drawable twice, but I can't see a way around that, unfortunately.